# Where is cassandra-cli

Tags: cassandra

I have installed Cassandra 3.7 using docker. I am reading a book which asks me to run a utility called cassandra-cli

however when I do a `find / -name cassandra-cli` I don't find this utility anywhere.

Do you know how can I install it? I guess this utility helps you in figuring out how the data is actually being stored by cassandra.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cassandra-cli` is deprecated and got [removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7920) since 2.2. Use [cqlsh](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html) instead.

Comment: The point which the book was trying to make was that cassandra-cli can show the data the way its actually stored. Is that something you can see with cqlsh? I think cqlsh only shows data as a table. not the way of nested maps.

Comment: Re: "the book": Which book is that? The Cassandra Definitive Guide? You should probably get the 2nd edition since you're using C* 3.7. Re: "show the data the way it's stored": indeed cqlsh will show data in tabular/relational fashion, but - in my opinion - as long as you wrap your head around the data model it's still making sense.

Comment: read [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958432/understanding-cassandras-storage-overhead) especially the answer which describes how to use sstable2json where I think the result is similar to cassandra-cli info.