# Running Cassandra CLI with SSL Enabled

Tags: ssl, cassandra, cassandra-2.1, cassandra-cli

what is correct command to run cli when SSL is enabled.

I am using cassandra 2.1.16 and running following command.

```
/etc/cassandra/bin/cassandra-cli -u <user_name> -pw <password> -p 10760 -h <hostname> --jmxusername <user_name> --jmxpassword <password> -ts /var/opt/keypath/abc.jks -tspw <password> --debug
```

It gives me following error:

> Login failure. Did you specify 'keyspace', 'username' and 'password'?

I looked at the source code of cassandra,but no gain, it simply returns the error message and there is no stacktrace.

Just for information: CQLSH is working fine on SSL.

Quick Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Casandra-CLI was marked as [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338816/where-is-cassandra-cli) and is lacking a lot of features. The recommandation is to use CQLSH. Since everything works fine in CQLSH, you should better use this one.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your comment but the requirement is such that I need to enable SSL for CLI too CQLSH is running fine on SSL.